# Array of strings to array of objects conversion

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an Array var category:

```
var category = ["all", "Items Id", "Items Sku", "Items Name"]
```

I need to convert it to a JSON object in the following format:

```js
var category = [{
  "id": "all",
  "text": "all",
  "children": [{
    "id": "Items Id",
    "text": "Item Id"
  }, {
    "id": "Items Sku",
    "text": "Items Sku"
  }, {
    "id": "Items Name",
    "text": "Items Name"
  }]
}, ];
```

I'm trying to work with the code below but doesn't work:

```js
var category = ["all", "Items Id", "Items Sku", "Items Name"]

var json = header.map((str, index) => ({ text: str, id: index + 1 }));

var categorylist = [];

for (var i in json) {
  categories.push({
    "id": json[0].value,
    "text": json[0].value,
    "children": [{
      id: json[i].value,
      text: json[i].value
    }]
  }

  console.log(categorylist)
```

Any help?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: FYI nothing about your question involves JSON. I've edited it accordingly.

Comment: Why do the children end up with different keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

map() for the children using a bit of destructuring to separate the first element from the rest of array

```js
const category = ["all", "Items Id", "Items Sku", "Items Name"],
      getObj = ([id,...rest]) => ({id,text:id, children: rest.map(id => ({id, text:id}))}),      
      res = [getObj(category)];

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array#map` to generate children skipping the first item and then generate your array by adding `id` and `text` for the first item and adding the children.

```js
const category = ["all", "Items Id", "Items Sku", "Items Name"],
      children = category.slice(1).map(id => ({id, text: id})),
      result = [{id: category[0], text: category[0], children}];
console.log(result);
```